# Create chart from single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I used a survey to collect data about people's opinion. The question is answered using a check-box (Yes/No). I would like to visualize the results using charts.

How can I do that using one column?

All the examples that I have seen are related to  graphs using two columns. For example:

```
col A   
 No      
 Yes     
 Yes
```

Pie chart : 66% YES - 33% NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no way to create a chart from a single column, you have to count the occurrences of the words first. Use the `COUNTIF`-function.

Here's an example: [Single Column Pie Chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z0aiKF4SLLrfdld4R_L5lWuRsl0V2HTT9ENu1DMLdfY/)

If you look at the two cells where the occurrences of the words is counted you can see two ways. Either searching for the content of a referenced cell or a static string.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Only more thing, Can I tweak this to make it contain instead of equality to overcome problems of blank and ascii characters =COUNTIF(E:E," contains F3"&F2)

Comment: Yes, I've updated my example spreadsheet. Use the `*` operator. It means "anything", so the `COUNTIF` counts the cell if it contains "anything and 'yes' and anything" (if the cell contains 'yes').

Answer (score 3):

Just select A1:A4, Insert > Chart...:

[image: WA58373 example]

Comment: Boom. Too easy.